# Who is the silver-haired girl from this picture?

Tags: the-pet-girl-of-sakurasou

[image]

I don't remember seeing this girl from the series. What is her name and how is she related to any of the characters?

Comment: She is [Otoha Nakano](http://d-game.dengeki.com/sakurasou/home/chara.html), however since I haven't seen this, I'll leave the full answer to someone else. Apparently she has a bigger role in the PSP/Vita game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's all I found.

**Nakano Otoha** (中野乙羽) first appears in the anime in episode 12 as part of the audience.

[image: audience.png]

She is one of the [credited characters](http://d-game.dengeki.com/sakurasou/home/chara.html) in the PSP/Vita game (presumably with a bigger role). Her seiyū is Yuka Ōtsubo (大坪 由佳).

[image: gamechar.png]

Translation of her profile:

> Suimei Art University Associated High School (a.k.a. Suikou) first year student. Although she is not a resident of Sakurasou, impressed by Sorata and co. performance, she told Sorata "I want to help". She is also the one who invites everyone to participate in "Super Creator Scouting Contest" this time around. Her favorite are vinegar kelp, which she always brings along and according to her would "blow away any fatigue", and making snacks for members of Sakurasou who are tired from making game from time to time.

[Wikia](http://sakurasounopetnakanojo.wikia.com/wiki/Nakano_Otoha) says about her personality:

> Nakano is an optimistic girl, her hair is tied into two ponytails. She was born in Montreal, Quebec. She moveｄ to Japan when she was 8. She stops　going to school at the age of 12 because an incident occurred where she was stabbed by a guy. She goes back to her school at the age of 17, starts her 5th year of junior high school. She finishes and graduates her junior high school at the age of 18. After she graduates, she goes to Suimei and she starts her 1st year of senior high school at the age of 19. 3 year later when the story is started, she is twenty-two years old now and she is a 1st year student.

She doesn't seem to be on [any of the drama CDs](http://vgmdb.net/search?q=pet+kanojo). At least, her seiyū isn't credited on any of them.